# Combining TensorProduct with NonCommutativeMultiply

Tags: tensors

I'd like to compute tensor products of lists that contain Grassmann variables, i.e. I'd like TensorProduct[] to use NonCommutativeMultiply when multiplying elements rather than the standard multiplication.

Ideally, this would not involve defining a new tensor product function from scratch but utilising the built-in one.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: `TensorProduct[array1, array2, ...]` is equivalent to `Outer[Times, array1, array2, ...]`; does simply using `Outer[NonCommutativeMultiply, array1, array2, ...]` work for you? (Note that if you have something like `GrassmannArrayQ`, you can redefine `TensorProduct`: `Unprotect[TensorProduct]; TensorProduct[a_?GrassmannArrayQ, b__?GrassmannArrayQ] := Outer[NonCommutativeMultiply, a, b]; Protect[TensorProduct]`.)

Comment: @thorimur Many thanks, that's exactly what I've been looking for! If you'd like to turn it into an answer I can accept it.